# I'm trying to read a json file, but compiler says, Parser cannot be resolved JAVA

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I've downloaded and added a `json-simple.jar` to my project in eclipse. The only problem is with the Parser, Eclipse says `"parser cannot be resolved"`. While the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` are working just fine.

I get the error when trying to read the file :

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("comments.json"));
```

imported as follows :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

I've just started using json, so i might be missing something.

The `comments.json` file is of this format :

```
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 1,
"name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
"email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
"body": "laudantium enim quasi est"
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `parser` to be?

Comment: I've edited the post, forgot to add the initialization part

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Unresolved compilation problem: 
parser cannot be resolved

Comment: You could try other JSON libraries like Jackson or Gson. `json-simple` is a little... too simple

Comment: Can you post the exact error and the comments.json?

Comment: i've put the format of the comments.json

Comment: Re: "Eclipse says 'parser cannot be resolved'": How does it say that? Is this a compile error, or a runtime error? In either case, please post the *complete, exact* error.

Comment: It's a compilation error! "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: parser cannot be resolved"

Comment: Hovering over org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser, gives the following note: "This element neither has attached source nor attached javadoc", the problem could be with the .jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer the Jackson library so I'm not as familiar with JSON.simple. Did you consider creating a `ContainerFactory()` for the parser? http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/parser/ContainerFactory.html

Also, your `"comment.json"` is just a `JSONObject()`, so no need in giving in the extra overhead of `JSONArray()`

Maybe give this a shot:

```
ContainerFactory cf = new ContainerFactory();
Map jsonContainer = cf.createObjectContainer(); 

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("comments.json"), jsonContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but as your json file has only one object, I prefer to use `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray`:

```
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("comments.json"));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
    System.out.println(name);
```